# C# regex to extract groups from input

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract anything between two colon's (**inclusive of the colon's**) in an arbitrary input using C#. Given

```
String input = "a:one:b:two:c:three:d";
```

I want

```
{string[3]}
[0]: ":one:"
[1]: ":two:"
[2]: ":three:"
```

Using

```
String[ ] inverse = Regex.Split( input, ":.*?:" );
```

I get the opposite of what I want...

```
{string[4]}
[0]: "a"
[1]: "b"
[2]: "c"
[3]: "d"
```

How can I inverse this or is there something more suitable than Regex.Split in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `:[^:]+:` 
1. Match a colon 
2. Followed by any non colon character one or more times.
3. Followed by a colon.

To get the set of matches use `MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(blah, ":[^:]+:");` instead of `Regex.Split`

Regex's are concise and powerfull but I find myself writting just as many comments as I would code when using them.

Comment: This returns the same result as he was getting with his first attempt.

Comment: +1 @Matthew.. yup u can see I came to the same conclusion (to use Matches) in my accepting comment to Chris (the other Chris) above.. just a slightly diff pattern.. I'm with you on the pros/cons of regex's.. when I write lines of code that I know could be replaced with a regex it drives me nuts but then if I decide to use a regex to replace those lines of code that process tends to drives me nuts also.

Comment: decided to give you the answer as you actually provided a solution as opposed to Chris who gave a suggestion and presumably you hadn't seen the comment to know the Q was already answered.. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just use a regular split (on ':'), extract every second element, and then append the colons back on? I think you're overcomplicating this.

Comment: TBH that way is more complicated than the way I'm going about it now. I'd like to do the split + grouping in one operation not many

Comment: What you're doing isn't splitting, because splitting does exactly what it says. It slices right down the middle. What you're talking about is matching, and it's way too late where I am to come up with an elegant regex for this pattern.

Comment: haha accepted on the basis that your right on both counts.. 1. I need a match not a split... MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches( input, ":.*?:"); will do the trick and 2. It's way too late to be coding AND|OR asking Qs on SO. Thanks for reminding me of both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(\w*):|:\w:|:\w$
```

Comment: Hi bernesto.. I'm assuming you mean to use that regex with Split rather than Matches.. I tried both ways and neither worked or I am not using it as u intended.. either way I will stick with original ans but thanks for posting.

Comment: This is a split. Tested and working. Thanks for your comment.